# How to programmatically trigger key press events in WinRT/C#/XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, input, windows-runtime, keypress

Today's mission was to enable a WinRT app to be remotely controlled.  With all the wiring in place, it was time to implement the remote control actions.  The simplest implementation for those actions was to simply simulate a key press inside the process.

Unfortunately, I was unable to find a way to do that.  I'm sure it's staring me in the face, but every solution I found online was either via PInvoke, Windows Forms or dialects of WPF that aren't available in WinRT.

Anyone know the magic incantation?

Thanks.

Comment: UI Automation? Search for IActiveAccessibility

Comment: I searched for IActiveAccessibility without a lot of success.  I also browsed the Windows.UI.Xaml.Automation namespace to see if there was anything serviceable in there.  There wasn't, as far as I could tell.  Got any other clues?  :-)

Comment: Just as aside, WinRT and WPF should be written in MVVM and thus you should never need to do UI automation. This should be considered an anti pattern and in the long run you will find this rather brittle.

Comment: Aron, if you have a suggestion for how an app should move the selected item around in a GridView when receiving an HTTP request, then I'm all ears.  My preferred approach would be to send in key press events.  The second (painful) option would be to track down the focused UIElement and use automation to do "the right thing" for each event.  What would you suggest?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373592(v=vs.85).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373592(v=vs.85).aspx - MSFT uses this internally for UX testing, this should allow you to generate input to your store app.

Comment: Larry: yeah, I saw that.  My scenario is not to automate the app from the outside, but from the _inside_.  I.e. I receive an HTTP request and I map that to input.  Imagine the app is playing video and the sender of HTTP requests is acting as a remote control.  Some of the commands in the remote control (like "move left") are best represented as keystrokes, because that enables all the existing infrastructure that knows how to handle a cursor key to just work.

Comment: @mfeingol It is polite to mark the best/correct answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not allowed to programmatically trigger a user-initiated event in WinRT XAML. The reason is, some API is restricted to be called only by user interaction. Programmatically causing such events would bypass this security mechanism.